# changing sliding tab position when NavigationDrawer item select

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, pagerslidingtabstrip

I want to change my sliding tab position and load the fragment assigned to that particular tab.I have implemented fragments for each tab like this

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        SongsFragment tab1 = new SongsFragment();
        return tab1;
    }
    else if(position == 1)            // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
    {
        VideoFragment tab2 = new VideoFragment();
        return tab2;
    }
    else if(position == 2)
    {

        FeaturedFragment tab3 = new FeaturedFragment();
        return tab3;
    }else{

    return null;

    }
}
```

I tried the following way to move to a fragment on NavigationDrawer item select.

```
 public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    if(position == 1){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new Dashboard()).commit();
    }

 }
```

But when i do this,it will move to the desired fragment but SlidingTabs won't be there.

If i can change the slidingtab position on navigationItem select it would be much easier. How can i do this?

Comment: y do u wish to have both sliding tabs and navigation drawer?

Comment: it's just something i want to do

Comment: check if ur replacing the container having sliding tabs as child...
change the layout file if it is so...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to do the following:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

}
```

This may vary though, depending on the exact implementation of sliding tabs you may be using.